# NSMutableArray of ClLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm trying to create then retrieve an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D objects, but for some reason the array is always empty.

I have:

```
NSMutableArray *currentlyDisplayedTowers;
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = { currentTowerLocation.latitude, currentTowerLocation.longitude };
[currentlyDisplayedTowers addObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&new_coordinate length:sizeof(new_coordinate)] ];
```

I've also tried this for adding the data:

```
[currentlyDisplayedTowers addObject:[NSValue value:&new_coordinate withObjCType:@encode(struct CLLocationCoordinate2D)] ];
```

And either way, the [currentlyDisplayedTowers count] always returns zero. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To stay in object land, you could create instances of `CLLocation` and add those to the mutable array.

```
CLLocation *towerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
[currentDisplayedTowers addObject:towerLocation];
```

To get the `CLLocationCoordinate` struct back from `CLLocation`, call `coordinate` on the object.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[currentDisplayedTowers lastObject] coordinate];
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting "CLLocation may not respond to +initWithLatitude:longitude:" even though I've added the framework and put '#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>' to the header. Sorry, this has got to be a really, really noob question :).

Comment: Here's the code: `CLLocation *towerLocation = [CLLocation initWithLatitude: currentTowerLocation.latitude longitude: currentTowerLocation.longitude]`

Comment: @Sina - I'm sorry that's not a class method. You need to call it as `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLocation:.. longitude:lon];`. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As SB said, make sure your array is allocated and initialized.

You’ll also probably want to use `NSValue` wrapping as in your second code snippet. Then decoding is as simple as:

```
NSValue *wrappedCoordinates = [currentlyDisplayedTowers lastObject]; // or whatever object you wish to grab
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
[wrappedCoordinates getValue:&coordinates];
```

Comment: yep, it's all allocated and initialized. still not working though :(.

Comment: allocating and initializing seems to have had no effect. does it make any difference that i'm doing all this while in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate your array.

```
NSMutableArray* currentlyDisplayedTowers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then you can use it.  Be sure to call release when you are done with it or use another factory method.

Comment: Thanks SB, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm also releasing and deallocing correctly I think (release once for each add, dealloc at the end).

Comment: You don't want to release per add.  Just release it when you no longer need a reference to the Array.

Comment: Gotcha. Still can't get the array to have any sort of count though. Any thoughts on what else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Might it have something to do with the fact that everything I'm doing is in a While loop?

Comment: You need to show more code.  Call count right after the add and see if it is > 0.  You might be recreating the array each time and referencing an empty one outside of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had `currentlyDisplayedTowers = nil` which was causing all the problems. Also, the previous advice to init and alloc were necessary. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, there's another solution if you are planning on using `MapKit`.

*(The reason I say **IF**, of course, is because importing a module such as `MapKit` purely for a convenient wrapper method is probably not the best move.. but nonetheless here you go.)*

```
@import MapKit;
```

Then just use MapKit's coordinate value wrapper whenever you need to:

```
[coordinateArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinateToAdd]];
```

In your example..

```
[currentlyDisplayedTowers addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:new_coordinate]];
```