# How to return a array list of non-object type in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have a method which should return a list of non-object types. Specifically a list of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. I would like to have it as a list and not as an `NSArray` I use the outcome to create a `MKPolyLine` using

```
+ (MKPolyline *)polylineWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords count:(NSUInteger)count
```

With the code below I get an "Array initializer must be an initializer" list.

```
 -(CLLocationCoordinate2D[])pathBetween:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)start and:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)end withNumberofPoints:(int)nrOfPoints{
CLLocationCoordinate2D returnPath[nrOfPoints];
for (int i=0; 1<nrOfPoints; i++) {
    float fraction=i/(nrOfPoints);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=[self coordinateAtFraction:fraction between:start andEnd:end forAccuracy:.02];
    returnPath[i]=coord;
}
return returnPath;
```

}

If I initialize the list using

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D returnPath[nrOfPoints]={};
```

I get "Variable sized object may not be initialized".
If I remove the [] from the method I get "returning 'CLClocationCoordinate2D[nrOfPoints]' from a function with incompatible result type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'"

Any Ideas?

Comment: I hope you realize that your code is trying to return a stack-allocated array, which by definition is invalid the moment you return from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D returnPath[nrOfPoints]`; value for noOfPoints should be available at complile time. if u replace line with `CLLocationCoordinate2D *returnPath = (CLLocationCoordinate2D *) malloc(nrOfPoints * sizeof (CLLocationCoordinate2D));` 
array would be available at run time. But I am not sure sizeof method will return the object size.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to create the array on the stack and then return it.  That won't work.

There are several things you can do here:

1. malloc the array of points.

   ```
   returnPath = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * nrOfPoints;
   ```

   This would mean the caller would have to free the returned pointer.
2. return the array in an `NSData`

   ```
   NSMutableData* returnData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * nrOfPoints];
   returnPath = [returnData mutableBytes];

   // the other stuff

   return [returnData autorelease];
   ```

   This means that you don't have to worry about memory management any more than for any other Objective-C object.
3. Have the caller supply the array e.g.

   ```
   -(void)    getPath: (CLLocationCoordinate2D*) returnPath // caller allocates a big enough buffer
              between: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)start 
                  and: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)end 
   withNumberofPoints:(int)nrOfPoints
   {
       // code as question but no allocation or return value
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you're adding returnPath values to returnData ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Kevin in the comment: you have to do something about the fact that your return argument is a local variable. The reference "returnPath" will point into Nirvana outside your function. Here is a video that explains what happens there, enjoy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E

For the array of CLLocationCoordinate2D, look at this post here:

[NSMutableArray of ClLocationCoordinate2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095333/nsmutablearray-of-cllocationcoordinate2d)

Hope this helps.