# Adding object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that builds a bounding box for annotations on a mapview. I am trying to add the current user's location as an annotation in order to make sure that they're included in the bounding box.

When I try to add the location to the NSMutableArray I'm getting a error that the parameter CLLocationCoordinate2D is incompatable with (id). When I make currentLocation a pointer (i.e. *currentLocation) I am getting an error that its incompatable.

What is the approperate way to add this object to the NSMutable array? Is there a better way about building this array?

```
- (void)zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [location coordinate];

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:currentLocation, nil];
    [annotations addObjectsFromArray:mapView.annotations];
...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095333/nsmutablearray-of-cllocationcoordinate2d possible answer

Answer (score 2):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a C struct type. This is no (OOP) object. Therefore you cannot add it to a Cocoa collection.

However, you can add `CLLocation` itself to the array or wrap `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into an instance of `NSValue`.

The first way would be the better one, because the annotations of the map view conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, which declares the method `-coordinate` which is provided by `CLLocation` instances, too.

```
- (void)zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:currentLocation, nil];
    [annotations addObjectsFromArray:mapView.annotations];

    // Build bounding box
    for( id location in annotations ) 
    {
      CLLocationCoordinate2D = [location coordinate];
      …
    }
...
}
```